# Create Date in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am not seeing it in the documentation but I am wondering if I can do something similar like in C#

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2019,01,01);
```

I would like to do that with moment

```
var d = moment(2019,01,01);
```

but that does not seem to work.

I can see I could do something like

```
var d = momment('2019-01-01');
```

but I want to do it separately so I can do something like

```
Datetime d = new DateTime(now.Year + 1, 01, 01);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use following constructor:

```
var d = moment({ year: 2019, month: 1, day: 1});
```

Or:

```
var d = moment([2019, 1, 1]);
```

Comment: hmm, I tried both ways  moment({ year: now.get('year'), month: 09, day: 31}).format('YYYY-MM-DD');  but I get 'Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode (63:49)'

Comment: Remove 0 before 9

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to inject your variables into the moment argument string:

```
let date = moment(`${moment().year()}-01-01`).add(1, 'years');
```